# How to get all possible years from the given day, day of the week, and month?

Tags: date, math, formula, rrule

I want to get the set of years which pertain to a *specific date, week of the day and month*. There are possibilities that I can get various years from this pattern. Suppose Date is 15, Month is August and Week of the day is Tuesday then, How would I find the years that are valid? Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 4):

Would this fully solve your problem?

The idea behind this:

- Start from the specific date (August 15th) from year 0
- if the date is on the specified weekday --> add it to your list
- add 1 year
- back to square 1

(till your specified MAX_DATE is reached)

```
List<Integer> validYears = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(0, Month.AUGUST, 15);
    while (date.getYear() < 2015) {
        if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY) {
            validYears.add(date.getYear());
        }
        date = date.plusYears(1);
    }
    validYears.forEach(year -> System.out.println(year));
```

Edit:
if your date is February 29th you should add following code (Because if you add 1 year to 0000-02-29 it will give you 0001-02-28, and from there on you will stay at the 28th)

```
if (date.isLeapYear()) { //And date was feb. 29
            date = date.withDayOfMonth(29);
        }
```

Heres a version with streams:

```
int day = 29;
Month month = Month.FEBRUARY;
List<LocalDate> collect = IntStream.range(0, 2016).filter(year -> day <= LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).lengthOfMonth())
            .mapToObj(year -> LocalDate.of(year, month, day)).filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

collect.forEach((year -> System.out.println(year)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple formula you can do even in your head.You can find more info here: [How to determine the day of the week, given the month, day and year](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node73.html)

1. Take the last two digits of the year.
2. Divide by 4, discarding any fraction.
3. Add the day of the month.
4. Add the month's key value: JFM AMJ JAS OND 144 025 036 146
5. Subtract 1 for January or February of a leap year.
6. For a Gregorian date, add 0 for 1900's, 6 for 2000's, 4 for 1700's, 2 for 1800's; for other years, add or subtract multiples of 400.
7. For a Julian date, add 1 for 1700's, and 1 for every additional century you go back.
8. Add the last two digits of the year.
9. Divide by 7 and take the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

This question relates to the classical Dommsday algo.
A simple method to calculate is Kraitchik's method.

Kraitchik method -
w = d + m + c + y mod 7,
where w is the day of the week (counting upwards from 1 on Sunday instead of 0 in Gauss's version);
and d, m, c and y are numbers depending on the day, month, and year as in the following tables:

```
Month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  
m       1   4   3   6   1   4   6   2   5   0   3   5
```

For the Gregorian calendar, take the century of the year (ex, the year 1986 would be 1900, 2014 would be 2000).
    [Century/100] mod 4:    0   1   2   3
    c:                      0   5   3   1

For the Julian calendar,
    [Century/100] mod 7:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
    c:                      5   4   3   2   1   0   6

Finally, the year number is obtained from this table (with 1 being subtracted from dates in January or February):
    Last two digits of the year                                             y
    00  06      17  23  28  34      45  51  56  62      73  79  84  90      0
    01  07  12  18      29  35  40  46      57  63  68  74      85  91  96  1
    02      13  19  24  30      41  47  52  58      69  75  80  86      97  2
    03  08  14      25  31  36  42      53  59  64  70      81  87  92  98  3
    09  15  20  26      37  43  48  54      65  71  76  82      93  99  4
    04  10      21  27  32  38      49  55  60  66      77  83  88  94      5
    05  11  16  22      33  39  44  50      61  67  72  78      89  95      6

That's it. You may obtain more background detailed info from wikipedia

Comment: I can't read that table. Maybe formatting was lost in the mobile app. If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: Detailed info on this topic is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week In your particular case, you need to make a modification, since you need to find the years. Maybe run a loop as well for a set of  centuries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in Java 8 using the LocalDate parser to do the work for you.  I used a modified version of this when I had a bunch of dates that had no year but were either the current year or the next one.

```
    String dateString = "Mon Dec 23";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d yyyy");
    Integer startYear = 2000;
    Integer endYear = 3000;

    List<Integer> validYears = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++){
      try{
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString + " " + i, formatter);
        validYears.add(localDate.getYear());
      } catch (Exception e){
        //Years that are not valid
      }
    }

    for(Integer year: validYears){
      System.out.println(year);
    }
```